# Command Line - Delete Files in Location 2 if they Exist in Location 1, then copy to Location 2

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command, line

I have looked through a lot of the questions here, and have put together about as much as I can without running into problems.

Goal - I want to check files in Folder 1 that have a date modified of > yesterday.  If they exist in Folder 2, I want them deleted in Folder 2.  Finally, I want to copy them over to Folder 2.

Here is what I have for the delete step.

```
cmd /k For %%F In ("Path_Folder_1\*.*") Do If Exist "Path_Folder_2\%%~nxF" Del "%%F" "Path_Folder_2\%%~nxF"
```

I figured I would do the copy step later, unless it can be combined with this step.  Also, I do not know how to integrate the date check into this.  I've seen "forfiles" but am not able to understand how to do the same thing with it.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: `XCOPY` has a `/U` switch that does this: `Copies only files that already exist in destination.`.  It also has  `/D` option to specify date but it will copy any files that are changed on or after the specified date.  So it would do today and yesterday's file if you specified the date to be Oct 4, 2018.  To only grab files with yesterday's date would be very difficult to do on a single line of code.

Comment: Really no point in deleting the file before copying over the file.  If you copy the file over it will just overwrite the file.

Comment: See also `help robocopy` which provides a more complete UI to the underlying library that xcopy calls into anyway.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and for for good measure, [MCVE]. Pretty sure this is a dupe, looking...

Comment: Well I can't find a close enough dupe, so I recommend that you consider the `/MIR` and `/MAXAGE` features of `robocopy`.